# Mage 2.1.1 short codes front end rendering

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block

I'm new to Mage 2 but familiar with M1. This is a M2.1.1 site

I'm attempting to output a static block in the product description by entering short code in the wysiwsyg editor like so:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

Even entering it in non-wysiwyg mode results in the same output:

{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}

is outputted rather than the static block.

However, if I use a widget to render the static block, all is ok.

Am I missing something fundamental - do I need to assign permissions to static blocks like in M1? Or is it possible that the template is at fault?

ps - what happened to the add widget/block buttons on the wysiwyg editor??

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? I mean, where in the admin panel.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I'm attempting to add the static block in the product description text area on a per product basis.

Comment: Ah ok. So the product description area, in both M1 and M2, do not accept these. This would require an extension or a customization.

Comment: No, sorry, in M1 you can add short codes in the product description - [code] {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}[/code] works as expected in M1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free extension to add cms block in product description https://github.com/magefan/module-catalog

Comment: Thanks for the link - seems odd the M2 requires an extension to achieve something so fundamental? This has been core in M1 since almost the outset.

Comment: The extension you provided looks like exactly what I was thinking, a simple plugin method to pass the description through the filter. Be aware that the extension linked to in the post also does some sort of modification on the breadcrumbs.